# Pourquoi utilise « constitutionnellement » dans cette phrase?

Tags: sens

[image]

Pourquoi utiliser « constitutionnellement » dans cette phrase?
S'agit-il de la loi?

Answer (score 3):

Il ne s’agit pas de la loi. Ici, on parle de la constitution de l’être humain : son état physique ou biologique.

Answer (score 3):

Ici il ne s'agit pas de la loi. Dans cet emploi il faut partir du mot **constitution** comme il est employé en psychologie.

Voir le [TLF. B.3.](https://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/constitution)

> PSYCHOL. Ensemble des caractères congénitaux d'un individu, à la fois somatiques, physiologiques et psychologiques, et qui constituent un type prédisposé à une certaine psychose.

Donc constitutionnellement ici veut dire **qui est lié à la constitution psychophysiologique d'une personne**.

Le mot constitution est aussi employé en biologie pour désigner la structure morphologique du corps humain, de l'organisme. Voir le [TLF. B.1.](https://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/constitution)